# How can I copy the Win8 metro File Picker UI

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm creating a Windows 8 metro style application for navigating a rest api which is essentially the same as a file system. I would like to use the same UI as you get with the File picker and the built in search results.

How can I get the XAML (or ideally XAML+code) used in this UI? Are there any samples? Could I use a tool? Is the code available anywhere?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: do you know about privacy policy? resharper can dissassemble class which you need ( You can only seen code do not copy it!) but I'm pretty sure you won't get XAML in any way

Answer (score 1):

The FilePicker is provided as an OS piece of UI that is common across all the WinRT dev environments.  There is not any source or XAML available for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just build it, right? The UI is so simplistic, that I think an hour and some TLC and you will have what you want. You can't get the raw XAML as it's in the OS itself, but you don't want it anyway - it's certainly implemented with more complexity than you want or need.

I would offer this one bit of advice. It makes sense to copy the general look of the file picker for the sake of usability. However, do yourself a favor and make something different. There's no reason the user should be confused by the similarity - wondering where their SkyDrive is or something else. You may have already thought of this.